# Jenkins multiple builds docker port conflicts

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a multi module Maven project, that i'm getting docker port conflicts when doing multiple Jenkins builds at the same time.

I'm using the docker-maven-plugin within my pom.xml files

How can I resolve this ?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
                <goal>build</goal>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <images>
            <image>
                <name>guest/guest-main:${project.version}</name>
                <alias>guest</alias>
                <run>
                    <env>
                        <myapp_ENDPOINT>http://mock:8081/mycalcService</myapp_ENDPOINT>
                    </env>
                    <namingStrategy>alias</namingStrategy>
                    <dependsOn>
                        <container>mock</container>
                    </dependsOn>
                    <links>
                        <link>mock:mock</link>
                    </links>
                    <ports>
                        <port>guest.port:8080</port>
                    </ports>
                    <wait>
                        <log>Started guestServiceApplication</log>
                        <time>60000</time>
                    </wait>
                </run>
            </image>
            <image>
                <alias>mock</alias>
                <name>guest/myapp-mock:${project.version}</name>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Regards

Comment: Why you need to expose the port at build time?

Comment: i'm fairly new to this - please explain

Comment: Are you using a Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration exposes `guest.port` to port `8080` of your Docker host system (e.g. your Jenkins) with the following line

```
<port>guest.port:8080</port>
```

Since a port can only be bind to one service at a time the later build will find it impossible to bind to that port.

To solve this you can either use a different port for each build or wait for the one port you'd like to use to be released by the other job.

For example you could add the following to your Jenkinsfile just before you execute `mvn`:

```
timeout(time: 10, unit: "MINUTES") {
    waitUntil {
        script {
            sh(script: 'netstat -lnpt 2>&1 | grep ":8080"', returnStatus: true) != 0
        }
    }
}
sh "mvn ..."
```

The `timeout` step causes Jenkins to cancel after 10 minutes.

The `waitUntil` step makes Jenkins retry the `script` until it succeeds.

A `script` is necessary since we do a caparison (`!=`) of the return value.

Finally `netstat` returns a list of currently bound ports and `grep` will return `0` only if port `8080` is one of those.